# My hot water heater uses about a 10th of a gallon an hour, no visible leaks , and when I turn the valves off to the hot water heater , the meter stops

Tags: plumbing, hot-water

My hot water heater seams to use water Aqua came out said my meters ok. My meter shows about a 10th of a gallon use per hour. When I turn the valves off to the hot water heater this meter progression stops. I'm just curious to where the water is going. 10th of a gallon an hour wouldn't that add up to a couple of gallons a day and 60 a month. It's hard to believe it's just evaporating.

Comment: Nothing is evaporating from inside a pressurized pipe.  Does turning the valve off to the hot water heater also turn water off to the hot water faucets? Because if so, shutting off the hot water isn't only testing the water heater but also all the hot water piping and every faucet in the house, including the one in the washing machine (and dishwasher if connected to hot).  And any recirculator foolishness that might be installed.

Comment: Yes no hot water anywhere and no recirculator. only a small expansion tank.

Comment: It's just weird where is the water going.

Comment: The water meters leak dial moves like a Mummer up 3 back 2 but generally progressing.

Comment: But all apparent leak indications stop when I turn off both valves to my hot water heater that I basically just use on the pilot setting. That enough for summer use.

Comment: "**both** valves to my hot water heater "??

Comment: Where is this, state and city? What type of foundation--slab, pier and beam, or full basement? A leak in the hot wate line between the water heater and the points of use is very common. The hot water in the pipes accelerates corrosion. Also the hot water pipes expand and contract with change in temperature and can cause the copper tubing to saw back and forth on concrete or rebar or stones in the ground. What kind of water heater do you have--gas fired tank, gas fired tankless, electric tank, electric heat pump . . .

Comment: Try turning off only the outlet valve. If the meter stops advancing this will be a sign that the heater itself is not where the loss/consumption is occurring.

Comment: Don't leave the outlet valve closed very long. You could build up pressure in the tank and cause the temp/pressure relief valve to dump water. This would complicate/confuse your investigation.

Comment: Most installations of tank wter heaters only have a shut-off on the cold inlet side of the water heater. Do you have one on the inlet and one on the outlet? A good quality tankless water heater will have one shutoff on the inlet and another on the outlet, but tanks mostly have a shutoff only on the inlet.

Comment: Please [read this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/editing) to learn about editing here on Stack Exchange sites (and why you shouldn't roll back improvements people make to your posts).

Comment: PS, it's "water heater", not "hot water heater".

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a 3rd bypass valve, by cutting off the supply to the water heater, you are also cutting off water to all of the hot water plumbing, and spigots, and everywhere else hot water goes, including washing machine, dishwasher and recirculation systems.

So you are failing to isolate the water heater *particularly*.

Also cutting off the outlet of the water heater does not change this.  If your hot water spigots no longer flow (any) water in this condition, then you have cut them off and you have also cut off any leaks in any spigot, piping, etc.  So of course those leaks will stop; you cut them off!

The only way you can successfully narrow the test to the water heater is to have a triple valve, i.e. a bypass valve, where you can cut off inlet and outlet to the water heater and then bypass the water heater to restore pressurized water to the hot water piping, spigots, etc.

If you don't already have a bypass valve, you could hard-plumb one in by simply piping around the water heater. Then re-open those valves and pressurize the rest of the system and see if the water leak is gone.

> It's hard to believe it's just evaporating.

It's not. If water flow is enough to make your meter observably move, then evaporation cannot explain it.

If it's observable on the gauge, it's either going directly down a drain, or making a big mess somewhere. So where would it be possible for it to simply go down a drain? Dishwasher? Running toilet? (toilets plumbed into hot, it has happened). Replenishment system in a hydronic furnace run amok?  Hot water line to an outbuilding that is leaking underground? How about a crawlspace?

Generally a water heater will reveal a leak either by leaving a puddle underneath itself, running water out its pan drain, or running water out its pressure relief valve plumbing to outside (which is there so people in the room don't get blasted by boiling water when the thermostat sticks on).

Comment: You could possibly presurize the hot water piping even with the cold supply to the hot water heater shut off if you have any mixing faucet in which the spigot can be capped, e.g., a utility sink faucet (utility sink in a laundry room or garage) which has hose threads. A sealing cap is sometimes on the end of a soaker hose so a trip to the home center might not be needed). Procedure is to cap the spigot then open hot and cold valves to presurize the hot water piping. Of course since these spigots are not designed to be pressurized they might leak and invalidate this as a leak testing method.

Comment: One way to test the hot water piping with equipment on hand would be to use the clothes washing machine supply connections. The hoses are each symmetrical (unless you have Floodsafe or other type). Turn off the two valves at the water heater. Pull the washer out, turn the valves off, disconnect the cold hose at the washer and the hot hose at the valve. Connect the free end of the cold hose to the hot valve. Open the two waher valves and the hot piping system would be pressurized. This would be some trouble but not as much as plumbing a bypass.

Answer (score 1):

If you turn off the inlet valve to the water heater and the meter stops moving, then there's a leak somewhere in the tank, hot water line or the pressure relief valve. If any of your water pipes go underground, they could be leaking there. If you have any heat recovery units tied into your AC unit or solar heat panels, check them for leaks too.

Answer (score -3):

As your water cools, its volume shrinks demanding top up.

A 180L tank will shrink require around 5 litre per day.

Comment: When I calculate it, I only get .18L  for a drop in 5degF.  Are you able to provide a reference?

Comment: As the water heats it expands again, though, right? Not like you're loosing water just by having the heater cycling...